# having issues getting a list of data from node.js to react.js

Tags: node.js, reactjs

i'm having issues getting response data from node.js to react.js, basically i'm trying to get a list of devices registered to a user and i want all those devices listed to a table but as of now i'm not getting any data from my node.js, i've done all i can to research google and read tutorials about this, i'm open to ideas and corrections. thank you.

Backend

```
app.get("/getdevice", (req, res)=> {
    let email = req.query.email;

    let stmt = `SELECT * FROM users WHERE email=?`;
    let todo = [email];

    
    db.query(stmt, todo, (err, results, fields) => {
      if (err) {
        console.error(err.message);
      }

      if (results.length > 0) {
        const userid = results[0].id;
        
        let statement = `SELECT * FROM controlModules WHERE deviceowner=?`;
        let task = [userid];
        
        //getting list of device
        db.query(statement, task, (err, results, fields) => {
          if (err) {
            res.send(err);
          }
          var array = [];
          for(let i = 0; i < results.length; i++){
            console.log(results[i].devicename);
            array[i] = results[i].devicename;
          }
          res.json({array});
        });
      }

    });

  });
```

Frontend

```
const Module = () => {
    const [show, setShow] = useState(false);

    const handleClose = () => setShow(false);
    const handleShow = () => setShow(true);

    const email = sessionStorage.getItem("email");
    const [device, setDevice] = useState([]);

    Axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;

    useEffect(() => {
        Axios.get("http://localhost:3020/getdevice", {
            params: {
              email: email
            }
          })
          .then(function (response) {
            setDevice(response);
          })
          .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
          })
    },[]);

    return (
        <div className="MainBodyM">
            <SDH/>
            <h3 className="deviceStatus"></h3>
            {/* <Button onClick={getDevices} variant="primary" type="submit">Refresh List</Button> */}
            <div className="tempHeader">
                {device}
            </div>
            
            <Link to="/registerdevice">
                <Button>Add Control Module</Button>
            </Link>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Module;
```

Comment: Have you tried logging axios response?

Comment: i haven't tried that one before

Comment: Then please try it and check if you are getting data from API or not

Comment: my concern is that i do not know how to properly get said data from the backend to the frontend as simple as possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should set `response.data` following the [axios's response schema](https://axios-http.com/docs/res_schema) (instead of `response` only).

```js
 Axios.get("http://localhost:3020/getdevice", {
            params: {
              email: email
            }
          })
          .then(function (response) {
            setDevice(response ? response.data || []);
          })
          .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
          })
```

then display it in `<pre></pre>` tag to make sure repsonse data's correct.

```js
 return (
        <div className="MainBodyM">
            <SDH/>
            <h3 className="deviceStatus"></h3>
            {/* <Button onClick={getDevices} variant="primary" type="submit">Refresh List</Button> */}
            <pre className="tempHeader">
                {JSON.stringify(device, null, 2)}
            </pre>
            
            <Link to="/registerdevice">
                <Button>Add Control Module</Button>
            </Link>
        </div>
    );
```

Comment: i tried your solution something but an error occurs ```Module parse failed: Unexpected token (36:25)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.``` on ```setDevice(response?.data || []);```

Comment: @IanDucao seem your version of es does not support optional chaining (?.), so just replace it with response ? response.data : []

Comment: thank you this works for me but one last question... how can i display just the data i want from the array of json? something like Device1 Serial#

Comment: you can use `.map()` of array to build the format of output array that you want. Eg: `const serials = devices.map(device => device.serial)`: it will return to you an array of serial only ([<serial1>, <serial2>,...])

Comment: I'm getting an error ```TypeError: device.map is not a function```